# Illegal character in path in released version but not in debug mode

Tags: c#, file, mvvm, path, long-integer

[image]TL;DR Why is it when running debug mode my application works but in release it does not?

I am using MVVM to load a file path to process some data.  When I am using the debugger version it loads, validates and converts fine, but when I am using the published/released version it fails so I am unable to track where it occurs.  One note is that we tried to accompanied long file paths so we included @"\\?\" 
Attached is our converter.

```
    public static string CheckFilePath(string filePath)
    {
        //Network Location
        if (filePath.StartsWith(@"\\"))
        {
            filePath = filePath.TrimStart(@"\\".ToCharArray());
            return @"\\?\unc\" + filePath;
        }
        //Local location
        if (!filePath.StartsWith(@"\\?\") && (!filePath.StartsWith(@"\\") || !filePath.StartsWith(@"\\?\UNC\")))
        {
            return @"\\?\" + filePath;
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```

Also we're using 4.6.2 and using this to try and accomodate long file paths.  Please note this is just my converter to check to see if it has a @"\\?\" or a @"\\" and replaces it with the following required for a long path.  This converter may not be the problem...  Any help would be great!

Comment: I would suggest adding tracing to your code, so that you can see what is going on in release mode.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Delete the bin folder which will force every thing to rebuild.  It sounds like you are not using the same source file for both debug and release.

Comment: Tried deleting the bin folder; during visual studio starting under release it works fine, but in the published version it still errors out.

Comment: Could you include the actual Exception / stacktrace?  Are you using the exact same test input for both builds?

Comment: I've attached the image of the exception

Comment: Yes I am using the exact test input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone thanks for the help, but I found a workaround.  Turns out there is something wrong with my published version versus my release version kind of like what jdweng said.  If I just run the executable from the release it works, but when I try to install it via publish, it does not.